# How to populate a dynamic value from a data extension and link it to the customer record by ContactUpdate Step in JourneyBuilder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql, subscriber-key, updaterecord

At the end of all journeys, I have a "Update Contact" activity step that captures a hardcoded values from journey branch to a data extension (to keep a track which branch customer is existing the journey).

Here is the data extension that is linked to "Contact Update" activity at the end of the journey:

| JourneyLOG_CaptureAtExit |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **CustomerID (subkey)** | **ExistStep** | NewCustomerID |
| 1 | Branch1 | null |
| 2 | Branch2 | null |
| 3 | Branch3 | null |
| 4 | Branch1 | null |
| 5 | Branch5 | null |

**Question:** I have another data extension where I have a mapping of Current_CustomerID and  NewCustomerID (this log keeps a track of customers who's ID have been changed).

| ContactsMapping |  |
| --- | --- |
| **Current_CustomerID** | **NewCustomerID** |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 202 |
| 3 | 303 |
| 4 | 404 |
| 5 | 505 |

I would like to capture the NewCustomerID with the help of "Update Contact" activity step from ContactsMapping DE to JourneyLOG_CaptureAtExit along with capturing the existstep.

**Desired output:**

| JourneyLOG_CaptureAtExit |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CustomerID | ExistStep | NewCustomerID |
| 1 | Branch1 | 101 |
| 2 | Branch2 | 202 |
| 3 | Branch3 | 303 |
| 4 | Branch1 | 404 |
| 5 | Branch5 | 505 |

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier do do that via sql in automation studio and have it run eg. every hour?

Comment: Yes, that is my backup solution but I am trying to see if there is another way within the journey to do this as customers are exiting the journey (instead of me adding an extra step / process to execute SQL). In that case, I will need to create a 3rd DE that links info from 2 DEs and combine into 1. Just trying to avoid creating multiple DEs at this point. Is there is any other way? Interested in learning new ways :)

Comment: You don’t need to create a third DE, you can update JourneyLOG_CaptureAtExit using sql and that’s it

Comment: ahh I see what you mean, in query join 2 tables and select table1.CustomerID, table2.NewCustomerID and use "Update" and it will update the 2nd column. Just curious, if I can do in journey builder as per my original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d go with SQL and an hourly automation as this seems the easiest:

```
SELECT
j.CustomerID,
j.ExistStep,
m.NewCustomerID

FROM JourneyLOG_CaptureAtExit j LEFT JOIN
ContactsMapping m

ON j.CustomerID = m.Current_CustomerID
```

And update the JourneyLOG_CaptureAtExit DE with results.

Comment: Thanks zuzannamj